# Corsair GS 180 slowdown in Macbook Pro over a year's time

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, performance

I installed a Corsair GS 180 SSD (revision 5.020000) in my Macbook Pro, around this time last year. (July 2012.) I ran the Blackmagic Disk Speed Test application, and ended up with:

```
Write: 219.0 MB/s
Read: 436.0 MB/s
```

But, a year later, the drive speed has decreased significantly:

```
Write: 107.8 MB/s
Read: 182.2 MB/s
```

Is there anything I can do to determine what caused the slowdown, or how to combat/reverse it?

I have the TrimEnabler app, but disabled it. Enabling it has not seemed to help!

Answer (score 1):

How long did you have TrimEnabler running?  It will only help over time, when through deleting files the SSD knows that the file clusters are no longer needed.

You can try to enable it, create a very large file (that takes up a significant chunk of your free space) and then delete it.

```
cd /tmp
mkfile 10240m 10Gigfile
rm 10Gigfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that might help is resetting the NVRAM and/or the SMC (here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4550751?start=0&tstart=0). Also, disable trim. It doesn't help at all, newer SSD's like yours have built in firmware that do a better job than trim. It might actually shorten the life of your SSD if you keep trying to use it.